# Flash, ActionScript 3.0 Tiles map

Tags: flash, actionscript, tiles

I want to build a Flash game using tiles (32x32) For a few years ago I used http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/start.html but I'm quite sure that is pretty outdated these days. I want to have scrolling as well (a big map).

Could someone provide me with some links that I can start off with? I have problem finding something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sense in re-inventing the wheel. For my two cents, I recommend using a game engine. Here is a list of the most popular ones:

http://www.flashrealtime.com/flash-game-library-engine-list/

It seems that http://flixel.org/ would fit your purpose. Have a look at their examples to get an idea on where to begin.